# how to disable #if DEBUG in C# at Win 7 visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-7

I am working on C# in Win 7 visual studio 2012.

I have `#if DEBUG` and I want to disable them. But, when I run C# in Visual Studio with "start without debugging", the `#if DEBUG` is still effective.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE

When I build my code in release, the `#if DEBUG` code is still there even though they are nor executed ? Do I need to remove them manually ? I need to get them removed after release. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your build configuration from Debug to Release.

Comment: when I release my code, the #if DEBUG code is still there even though they are nor executed ? Do I need to remove them manually ? I need to get them removed after release. Thanks !

Comment: The #if DEBUG really checks for a compilation flag. When you're in debug mode, that flag is set. However, in release mode that flag is NOT set, therefore code that is wrapped in #if DEBUG statements will not execute.

Comment: I know this. But, what if I want to remove the "#if DEBUG" from the files ? I do not want others see them when I deliver the c# code. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're already building against the "Release" built profile so I'll explain how to unset the DEBUG constant for release.

Right-click on the project and in the *Build* section remove flag from "Define DEBUG constant".
This flag should be removed only for the "Release" built profile and set for the "Debug" built profile.

When you choose "Start without debug" you are not telling to built for release, but just to not attach the debugger to the process.

Those are 3 different but inter-related things: built profile (Debug/Release), starting with or without debugger attached to the process and setting/unsetting the "Define DEBUG/TRACE constant".

Answer (score 0):

"Start without debugging" *only* means that VS will not attach the debugger to the running process; it doesn't change anything else. You're probably running using the Debug configuration - if you want to compile in Release, you should choose Release from the dropdown in the toolbar, where you should currently see a dropdown set to Debug.

Visual Studio creates these configurations for your project to start, which control what preprocessor flags are set to, as well as a bunch of other configuration (how much optimization to use, etc.). You can edit them if you want, or even create new ones.